# WSO2 Java EE dynamic web project(Jax-Rs) deploy on Application Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I have developed Jax-Rs service(send http request to SOAP wsdl service) and it can be deployed on **Tomcat** which is on my machine, it works well.

When i deploy on WSO2 Application Server 
**it gives me below error :** 
[image]

**It is full stacktrace :**

```
 REQUEST Caused Error : javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:336)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:325)
        at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:46)
        at com.ofss.fcubs.gw.ws.types.FCUBSCcyService.getFCUBSCcyServiceSEI(FCUBSCcyService.java:72)
        at com.org.service.BranchCurrencyRate.getBranchCRate(BranchCurrencyRate.java:272)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.statistics.webapp.RequestIntercepterValve.invoke(RequestIntercepterValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.bam.webapp.stat.publisher.WebAppStatisticPublisherValve.invoke(WebAppStatisticPublisherValve.java:104)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.create(WSDLServiceFactory.java:183)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromWSDL(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:428)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:548)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:265)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:214)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:101)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:90)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:155)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:156)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.createPort(ServiceImpl.java:467)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:334)
        ... 54 more
Caused by: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaException: Unable to locate imported document at 'http://172.25.0.188:8003/FCUBSCcyService/FCUBSCcyService?xsd=1', relative to 'http://172.25.0.188:8003/FCUBSCcyService/FCUBSCcyService?wsdl#types1'.
        at org.apache.cxf.catalog.CatalogXmlSchemaURIResolver.resolveEntity(CatalogXmlSchemaURIResolver.java:76)
        at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.resolveXmlSchema(SchemaBuilder.java:684)
        at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleImport(SchemaBuilder.java:538)
        at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleSchemaElementChild(SchemaBuilder.java:1513)
        at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleXmlSchemaElement(SchemaBuilder.java:659)
        at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:540)
        at org.apache.cxf.common.xmlschema.SchemaCollection.read(SchemaCollection.java:129)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.SchemaUtil.extractSchema(SchemaUtil.java:140)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.SchemaUtil.getSchemas(SchemaUtil.java:73)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.SchemaUtil.getSchemas(SchemaUtil.java:65)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.SchemaUtil.getSchemas(SchemaUtil.java:60)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder.getSchemas(WSDLServiceBuilder.java:372)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder.buildServices(WSDLServiceBuilder.java:339)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder.buildServices(WSDLServiceBuilder.java:203)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.create(WSDLServiceFactory.java:175)
        ... 64 more
```

I am using Java HttpUrlConnection, I guess it cannot send http request to this URL

Comment: Where are the xsd/wsdl hosted. On your local machine where you also run tomcat? Is WSO2 running there as well?

Comment: Wso2 running well, tomcat is running on Eclipse (Server), path set to program files ->tomcat directory
They are in WEB-INF/jax-ws-catalog.xml,
Actually i commented xsd files in jax-ws-catalog, after deployment it was not working, but now it works suddenly, idk why lol